# Squirrel Client DB2 Stored Procedure Session Delimiter

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, squirrel-sql

I am facing a tricky problem while I am trying to run stored procedure via Squirrel against DB2 database.
In the stored procedure have part where combine an sql statement like this:

```
SET V_SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' || PARAM_COLUMNNAME || ' FROM '||PARAM_TABLENAME||' WHERE '||PARAM_COLUMNNAME||'<'||PARAM_NUMBER||';';
```

I changed the session statement paramater ; --> @ to run properly the procedure call, but I get error message:

> An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may
>   include:  "WHERE REP_ID<201506".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   DRIVER=3.59.81 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601

I guessed it is because of the delimeter ';' of the inside `sql` script so I changed the code like this:

```
SET V_SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' || PARAM_COLUMNNAME || ' FROM '||PARAM_TABLENAME||' WHERE '||PARAM_COLUMNNAME||'<'||PARAM_NUMBER||'@';
```

Then I get this message:

> The numeric literal "201506@" is not valid.. SQLCODE=-103,
>   SQLSTATE=42604, DRIVER=3.59.81 SQL Code: -103, SQL State: 42604

Do you have any idea?

> Squirrel: SQuirreL SQL Client snapshot-20150623_2101 DB2: 9.5

Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: You do not need a terminator in your dynamic SQL, because you can only run one statement at a time: `'<'||PARAM_NUMBER;`

Answer (score 0):

So finally what for me worked it was the comment sign:
SET V_SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' || PARAM_COLUMNNAME || ' FROM '||PARAM_TABLENAME||' WHERE '||PARAM_COLUMNNAME||'<'||PARAM_NUMBER||';';--

The explanation I am not sure why pass through in this way the database engine, but worked.
Thanks!